# Grid Mass Action getting required-entry class

Tags: magento2, grid

How to remove required-entry class for the grid MassAction dropdown field.

[image]

In ui_component iam having only the following files:

csmarketplace_vendor_edit0000.xml

`

* @copyright   Copyright CEDCOMMERCE (http://cedcommerce.com/)
  * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
  */
-->

    
               
            separator-top
            SOP MassPriceUpdater - Price Configuration
            catalog
            Soulof_MassPriceUpdater::masspriceupdater_config
            
                General Configuration
                
                    Category / Categories
                    
                        
                           Selected category products price will be updated]]>
                    
                    required-entry
                    Soulof\MassPriceUpdater\Model\Config\Source\CategoryList
                
                
                    Price type(s)
                    
                        
                           Selected price type(s) will be updated]]>
                    
                    required-entry
                    Soulof\MassPriceUpdater\Model\Config\Source\PriceAttribute
                
                
                    Update type
                    
                            **If you select 'fixed', please fill the field price**
                            **If you select 'percentage', please fill the field percentage**]]>
                    required-entry
                    Soulof\MassPriceUpdater\Model\Config\Source\PriceType
                
                
                    Price
                    
                        
                
                
                    Percentage
                    
                        
                            For example: -20% or 20%]]>
                
            
        
    
`

And product_price_assign_form.xml

`

```
<fieldset name="contact">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sample Fieldset</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <!-- This field represents form id and is hidden -->
    <field name="pfay_contact_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">contact</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <!-- This field has data type 'text' and standard 'input' form element and looks like input -->
    <field name="name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Name</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">contact</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>


    <!-- This field has data type 'text' and standard 'input' form element and looks like input -->
    <field name="email">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Email</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">contact</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

</fieldset>`
```

Comment: Share your ui_component xml code.Such that it will be useful to identify the issue..